# Codenameone Load overFlow menu

Tags: codenameone

I have customized my form titlebar and added buttons to it. Is it possible to add a listener to one of the buttons to add command(s) an overflow menu and show it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, command/s can be added to overflow menu by using the following codes and actionPerformed is called when click on the command

```
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
f.setToolbar(toolbar);
toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(new Command("Test") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          showForm("NewForm",null);
        }

    });
```

Comment: This one works, but I want to call the overflow menu from a button created dynamically.

Comment: Currently one command is overflowmenu and if you add button then you have customized as per you needed.

Comment: You can add/remove commands dynamically from the Toolbar. You can also use `addCommandToRightBar` and do the whole menu showing process manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please try this it displays overflow menu when you click on button.

  void showOverFlow(final Form f) {
    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
    f.setToolBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(new Command("overflow"));
    Button button = new Button("show menu");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            if (f.getToolbar() != null) {
                MenuBar mb = f.getToolbar().getMenuBar();
                if (mb != null) {
                    mb.showMenu();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    toolbar.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST,button);

}
```

Comment: This works okay. Is there a way I can hide the Overflow menu icon?

Comment: the menu hide when user click on screen and this code can be used 

Button cancel= new Button("cancel menu");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                if (f.getToolbar() != null) {
                    MenuBar mb = f.getToolbar().getMenuBar();
                    if (mb != null) {
                        f.revalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Want it hidden when the form is being loaded.